# Accessing Local Apache Subdomain from iPhone

Tags: apache, testing, subdomain, localhost, remote-debugging

I can currently access my localhost by typing my IP into Safari on my iPhone, but I have a mobile subdomain that I want to access (m.mysite.local). How can I access this subdomain from my iPhone?

Thanks!